# How can I solve a conflict between a select2 search field and a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I have a get a conflict with select2 and boostrap modal. I cannot use the search field anymore:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.select2').select2();

  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
  })
  
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.select2').select2('destroy');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>
<select class="select2" style="width: 100%;">
   <option>one</option>
   <option>two</option>
   <option>three</option>
</select>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <select class="select2" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option>one</option>
                        <option>two</option>
                        <option>three</option>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution for the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.select2').select2();

  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
     $('.select2').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
     });
  })

  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.select2').select2('destroy');
  })
});
```

Comment: I have similar issue in select2 with the summer note modals in bootstrap4. These two things use the same class `show.bs.modal` and it creates issue like modal frizzing and not closing.